# How to implement Server side include with navigation links

Tags: asp-classic, server-side-includes, ssi, shtml

I have 4 html pages. 1 of them is having common UI which needs to be available on all the other pages.

In navigation page there are 3 links which points to the other 3 pages. I have used include to have this common file in all the three. 

I am not getting how to handle the link click events and change the page accordingly.

Can anyone please help me in achieving this ?

Thanks in advance.
Vijay

Comment: have you considered using the master page concept?

Comment: Yes. The similar kind of effect I am trying to produce. Giving it a try.

Answer (score 0):

For simple requirement like this, I suggest you to use standard html iframe

Comment: yes but I am considering some server side processing as well. So going for SSI. Otherwise I have created an application with iframe as well.